# Why does AUTOEXTEND not extending UNDOTBS1?

Tags: oracle

I have AUTOEXTENSIBLE turned on with MAXBYTES set to 32GB but UNDOTBS1's size stays as 2GB and I'm getting "ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS1'.

I have almost no experience with databases so unfortunately, that's all info I can provide.

Comment: Ask DBAs (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle), we're mostly developers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AUTOEXTEND means that a tablespace might grow until the maxsize is reached, **as long as you have enough space in your underlying device**

Let's imagine you have an UNDOTBS tablespace in your database with MAXSIZE 32GB and you cannot grow beyond 2GB

```
SQL> SELECT FILE_NAME FROM DBA_DATA_FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'YOUR UNDO TABLESPACE' ;
```

If your data file is Linux, please do the following

```
df -h /path_where_the_undo_file_is
```

The most probable scenario is you ran out of space in your FS or DISK where the undo datafile is located.

Hope it helps.
Regards

Comment: Looks like the administrator did not constrain the main table so it filled the entire disk space... Thank you for help